# How to cite ACM Computing Classification System?

Tags: publications, citations, bibtex

In the research I'm doing for my master thesis I use the [ACM Computing Classification System](https://www.acm.org/about/class/2012) (2012 edition).

I mean I literally use the data they provide as an RDF graph. How should I cite this classification system? Ideally I'm looking for a bibtex snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to use the *ACM Computing Classification System* as a **data set**, rather than a *publication*, I recommend to use rules, established in the publication style guide for citing *data sets*. The only potential change I would consider is substituting the type of reference from `[Data set]` to `[Data set -- Ontology]` or, even, just `[Ontology]`. That is, of course, if your institution is not too inflexible on deviations from publication style standards. Otherwise or if you want to be on the safe side, just use the standard `[Data set]` identifier.

Check the following relevant resources on citing data sets, based on APA as well as other publication style guides. It should not be a problem to convert your ACM CCS citation to `BibTeX` format by using `@misc` entry type and including `[Data set]` into a relevant field (location-wise).

---

**Resources:**

- Official APA blog post ["How to Cite a Data Set in APA Style"](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2013/12/how-to-cite-a-data-set-in-apa-style.html);
- Examples by MSU Libraries [How to cite data: Dataset citations](http://libguides.lib.msu.edu/c.php?g=96245&p=626239) (various styles);
- Excellent comprehensive article ["How to Cite Datasets and Link to Publications"](http://www.dcc.ac.uk/resources/how-guides/cite-datasets).

---

**UPDATE:** (initial attempt - alternatively, delete publisher / address and use "ACM" as author)

```
@misc{Acm:2012,
  author = "",
  title = {{ACM} Computing Classification System {[Data set].}},
  howpublished = {Retrieved from \url{http://dl.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=2371137&ftid=1290922&dwn=1}},
  note = {Accessed: 2015-06-21},
  year = {2012},
  publisher = {Association for Computing Machinery, Inc.},
  address = {New York, NY}
}
```

Comment: You can also use `@electronic` or `@online` entry tags instead of `@misc`. Just make sure that generated citation's formatting is acceptable, as AFAIK it sometimes significantly depends on the entry tag used.

Comment: Thanks a ton! But why the authors part is empty? Shouldn't it be something like "Bernard Rous et al"? (or some people from [here](https://www.acm.org/about/class/2012?pageIndex=2))

Comment: @AlexeyGrigorev: You're very welcome! As for the authors, these types of resources usually have too many authors to mention, so, unless there are clearly specified editors for a specific reference in question (in this case, you can mention Editor-in-Chief, as listing all editors is IMHO not feasible), I would leave the `authors` field empty. So, I would just add the following field: `editor = {Zvi Kedem}` (don't forget the trailing comma).

Answer (score 2):

There is also a paper that describes the update to the ACM CCS, which you might cite since it has a DOI. The paper itself is at http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2366320, and the DOI is http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2366316.2366320.

Comment: While I understand your point in regard to DOI availability (which should always be preferred under _equal conditions_), I think that the OP's clear intent is to cite the ACM CCS **data set** per se, not a relevant publication, describing it.

Comment: It's amusing. The usage instructions request "that copies bear ... the full citation", but I can't find any recommended format for such a citation. There is a published article about it, though, which may be the best you can do.

Comment: "The full citation" IMHO implies the one, which is governed by a chosen or required publication style guide, hence my answer. Most style guides recognize data sets as valid objects for citation.

Comment: Sure. I upvoted your answer. Mine isn't contrary. Just supplemental.

Comment: Absolutely (upvoted as well). It is a pity that ACM does not provide a DOI for such a popular and important data set (ontology).

Comment: Agreed. I thought it was odd. Maybe OP can send Bernard Rous a note.